# Is there a way to combine columns of data (not merge or concatenate)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

To use an example, I have 2 columns of data that I need to combine into 1...

This is the data I have:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | Red |
| Yellow | Green |

This is what I want the formula to do:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Blue |
| Yellow |
| Red |
| Green |

Tried searching on Google but results keep showing merge and concatenate. Maybe this is because I can't word it correctly...

I've tried ={Column A, Column B etc.} and FILTER() but I appear to be way off

Answer (score 1):

To copy all values into a *different column*, use `flatten()`, like this:

`=flatten(A1:B)`

That gets values in a rows-first order. To get them in a columns-first order, use `query()` and an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

`=query( { A1:A; B1:B }, "where Col1 is not null", 0 )`

To place the values in column `A`, without copying the values into new column, put this formula in the first blank cell in column `A`:

`={ B1:B }`

To *move* the values in `B1:B` to below the values in `A1:A`, you will need a script. A spreadsheet formula cannot move or delete existing values.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A1:B)), "where Col1 is not null", )
```

[image]